# how to listen facebook share callback

Tags: php, html, facebook, api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Im wondering how to do this, once we click share button, we get a popup box and there if we click SHARE button then that will be shared on facebook, and after clicking it the dialog closes, I want to handle it after a successful share, I want to award users who actually finish sharing(not just clicking and closing dialog), how can I listen to this kind of callback in FB share ?

Comment: Awarding the user something for sharing is not allowed according to Facebook Platform Policy https://developers.facebook.com/policy . And the most likely thing that will happen is that your website will be blocked from sharing at all

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the JS SDK, you can use the `FB.ui()` method to trigger the Share Dialog (not the Share Button), as described here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui/#examples

Sample Code:

```
function callShareDialog() {
    FB.ui(
      {
        method: 'share',
        href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
      },
      function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error_code) {
          alert('Posting completed.');
        } else {
          alert('Error while posting.');
        }
      }
    );
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<a href="#" onClick="callShareDialog()">Link</a>
```

Besides the actual code, please make sure that you adhere to the Platform Policies to avoid a ban of your app/website.

Comment: Thanks, but when I add this code to my existing share button code that didnt help, this is even not displaying the share button, found this same code in many articles but not sure how to use it, can you help me with full HTML?

Comment: Yes, you were correct :), and I managed it to work some how, now it just opens the dialog when window loads, can I tune it to load on click of a link?